# Using OpenGL ES 2.0 Extensions with Marmalade SDK

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, marmalade

I want to use some of the non-standard GLES 2 extensions like 'GL_OES_vertex_array_object' but I can't find a way to use them with Marmalade SDK. I guess I have to initialize them with a marmalade related function like the wglGetProcAddress on Windows but I can't find anything about this on the net. Currently my code compiles fine, but on the linking process I get "unresolved external symbol" errors. Is there a way I can use these extensions with Marmalade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in [Marmalade Documentation](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/documentation#/api/iwglapidocumentation/iwglapioverview/iwglextensions.html).

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed that:)

Answer (score 0):

I am one of the Marmalade SDK developers, and as I know support of GLES2 drivers was not finished yeat. This functionality should be released somewhere in the end of August. I know defenetly that it will not work for OSX.